# error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException No such property: sql for class: Script9

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to compare two values in data format

```
import groovy.sql.*
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" )

def messageId1 = context.expand( '${#Project#Id1}' )
def messageId2 = context.expand( '${#Project#Id2}' )

def first = sql.firstRow("select timestamp from table where Messageid = '"+messageId1+"'")
def second = sql.firstRow("select timestamp from table where Messageid = '"+messageId2+"'")

assert first <  second, 'OK'
```

I get following error:

`error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException No such property: sql for class: Script9`

Comment: You 'sql' property is not initialized. Try to init it before calling: 'def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)' for example

Comment: Thanks! But now I get next error: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot compare groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult with value '{TIMESTAMP=2018-02-20 14:40:33.513}' and groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult with value '{TIMESTAMP=2018-02-20 14:40:33.616}' error at line: 22

Comment: Groovy will happily carry out string comparisons.  E.g. assert '{TIMESTAMP=2018-02-20 19:40:33.513}' < '{TIMESTAMP=2018-02-20 14:40:33.616}';.  I checked this works and made it fail by changing 19:40 to 22:40.  Try turning the values into strings, e.g. first.toString() and second.toString()

Comment: One more point, the second param in the assert, where you have 'OK', is actually the message when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the mistake that I made is, I didn't create a SQL Instance...So  this would help you

```
def DBurl = '<Your database URL>'
def DBuser = '<Database user name>'
def DBpassword = '<Database Password>'
def DBdriver = '< Your database driver>'
def sql = Sql.newInstance(DBurl, DBuser, DBpassword, DBdriver)
```